# How can i set the app configuration values for a React app in Azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure, visual-studio

I have a React app deployed to Azure. Now in my code i want to use the settings from the Configuration section in my react app in Azure. At the moment i am putting values in the "launchsettings.json" file and reading them in my react app as follows:

```
      Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(<the name of the section>)
```

I have noticed that the launchsettings.json file is not deployed. So do i need to add those values in the Configuration section of the Azure app .I alos connect to an azure db via a direct connection string in the code , i want to put it in a config file of some sort .

Also when i want to read them in the app is it

```
   Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable   or ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues()
```

Which do i use in my app and why isnt the launchsettings.json file being deployed from Visual Studio ?

I tried to copy the launchsettings file manually , but that didnt work .. cani deploy it with the app ?

Comment: Can you please add launchsettings.json file in the above question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pull connection strings or app settings from the hosting server in a react app because you have no backend code.

You need a backend API or some other form of server side code to do what you're trying to do.